# Dynamically inserted child components access in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm using [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/3dzkMVXe4AGSRhk11TXG?p=preview) example to dynamically create components in my app.

```
  export class App {
   @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef;
   private componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;

   constructor(componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, compiler: Compiler) {
    this.componentFactory = componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
  }

  addItem () {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);
  }
}
```

Here is the question. Since this components tracked as @ContentComponents how can I inject data to this type of components?

I try like this:

```
 @ContentChildren(TextComponent) components: QueryList<TextComponent>;
```

now I successfully obtain QueryList of my TextComponent's
then I try something like this:

```
this.components.forEach(x => x.Message = "Content component");
```

and there is no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  addItem () {
    var cmpRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0);
    cmpRef.instance.someProp = 'someValue';
    cmpRef.instance.someObservable.subscribe(val => this.val = val);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is there any refferences on the documentation? I want to read about ViewContainerRef, and createComponent function.

Comment: AFAIK only https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactoryResolver-class.html, and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html